# Python: next() function returns unexpected 'None'

Tags: python, iterator

it's my first question ever so I'll try to be as clear as I can.
I noticed the next() functions and it seems a more elegant solution to use than the classical nested loop.
So I run a simple code:

```
liste=['foo','bar','baz']

try:
    G= (print(x) for x in liste)
    print(next(G))
    print(next(G))
    print(next(G))
    print(next(G))

except StopIteration:
    print("That was obviously expected")
```

And I'm expecting:

```
foo
bar
baz
That was obviously expected
```

to appear on my screen, but instead I got:

```
foo
None
bar
None
baz
None
That was obviously expected
```

So my question(s) is simple:

**Why are there `None` responses after run ?**

**What is the good way and when is it the good moment to use `next()` ?**

Thanks

Comment: You are printing the result of the print function. Change the line G = (x for x in liste)

Comment: print returns None, so G is a generator of Nones, change `print(x)` to x

Comment: Ok pretty dumb, I must agree. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `print()` returns `None`.

You are essentially doing `print(print(..))`. The inner `print` prints as you would expect (`'foo'`, ...) but the outer *prints the print* which is where the `None` comes from.

Answer (score 0):

```
liste=['foo','bar','baz']

n = iter(liste)

print(next(n))
print(next(n))
print(next(n))
```

Explanation:

This is an example for generator. Using `iter` and `next` we can generate the values

```
n = iter(liste)

print(next(n))
```